# How to determine version of openssl library?

Tags: c++, openssl

I have a pre-built OpenSSL library (libssl.a and libcrypto.a) which are being used for my C++ application. I don't know the version of the OpenSSL library.

Is there any way to get the version number from these pre-built libraries?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this programatically by reading the following:

- [`OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER(3)`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER.html)

and

- [`SSLeay_version(3)`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/SSLeay_version.html)

Basically, you will need to use the following functions:

- `SSLeay()`
- `SSLeay_version()`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you provide a code example for this? I am using this for iOS platform.

Comment: @Naseef: does [this](https://github.com/ppelleti/https-example/blob/master/https-common.c#L39) help?

Comment: Yes it as helpful. I am checking it. Will let you know about the updates. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Naseef: The example is simply `cout << SSLeay_version(SSLEAY_VERSION);`. after, of course, initializing the library with `SSL_library_init ();`.

Comment: @Laszio Papp Please see my edited comment. I just overlooked the link you gave in the comment. I was wondering about the code, that where it is taking library path?

Comment: It is already linked against openssl, so why would any path be needed?

Comment: The path where my pre-built libraries are located.

Comment: It is **already** loaded, so there is no path to deal with. The program knows that it is loaded, the function is available, and it will initialize the internal state of the library and so on. I am not sure what path, and why for that matter, you are talking about.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51525/discussion-between-naseef-and-laszlo-papp)

Comment: @Naseef: you link your application against openssl since you want to use it. The path is all handled before the linkage stage... You do not need to supply it explicitly again. Please select an answer once the issue is resolved.

Comment: The issue is not resolved yet. I will select an answer once it will be resolved.

Comment: May be I am doing some silly mistakes. Have u used this code yourself? What I have done is copied the code and removed some unnecessary code. But when I run the code after compiling it shows lots of build errors. I am trying to overcome these errors.

Comment: @Naseef: you need to use -L/path/to/the/library -lssl for linkage.

Answer (score 35):

There is a string inside the library containing the version details called [SSLEAY_VERSION](https://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/OPENSSL_VERSION_NUMBER.html) - it looks like:

- `OpenSSL 0.9.5a 1 Apr 2000`
- `OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013`

You can find this from the binary library using strings and grep:

```
strings libcrypto.so | grep "^OpenSSL \S\+ [0-9]\+ \S\+ [0-9]\+"
```

Comment: Yes. It works with static libs. Which means you can find out the OpenSSL (or maybe any other lib) version, when you know that it was statically linked to the binary. Simply use the binary as the input for the strings command. Neat!

Comment: cygwin saves the day again! Using this on DLLs works well too.

Answer (score 17):

Well the filtering may may not always work. You could do

```
strings libssl.so | grep "^OpenSSL"
OpenSSLDie
OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017

strings libcrypto.so | grep "^OpenSSL"
OpenSSLDie
OpenSSL_add_all_ciphers
OpenSSL_add_all_digests
OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017
OpenSSL HMAC method
OpenSSL EC algorithm
OpenSSL RSA method
OpenSSL DSA method
OpenSSL ECDSA method
OpenSSL DH Method
OpenSSL X9.42 DH method
OpenSSL PKCS#3 DH method
OpenSSL ECDH method
OpenSSL 'dlfcn' shared library method
OpenSSL default
OpenSSL default user interface
OpenSSL CMAC method
```

Answer (score 12):

You could also use :

```
openssl version -a
```

See reference at : https://linux.die.net/man/1/version

Comment: That only returns the version of the binary in /usr/bin or wherever along with compiler flags. It does not return the version of the library file(s) which are typically in /usr/lib

Answer (score 1):

I needed a variant of https://stackoverflow.com/a/26635393/597742 that would work on systems without `strings` installed. It's sufficiently different that it seemed worthwhile to post as its own answer:

```
grep --text -o 'OpenSSL [[:digit:]][^ ]*' /file/to/check
```

`--text` allows the binary to be checked directly, `-o` accounts for the lack of line separators by only printing the matching text.

A point worth noting for both this answer and the `strings` based answer: in addition to being useful to check the OpenSSL version of `libssl` or `libcrypto`, they also work to check OpenSSL versions in statically linked binaries.

Answer (score 1):

On a Debian you might ask the package manager:

```
# apt list -a openssl 
Listing... Done
openssl/stable-security,now 1.1.1n-0+deb11u4 amd64 [installed,automatic]
openssl/stable 1.1.1n-0+deb11u3 amd64
```

On a RedHat linux ask its package manager:

```
$ dnf list --all openssl
Last metadata expiration check: 0:01:53 ago on Mon 13 Mar 2023 01:14:50 PM UTC.
Installed Packages
openssl.x86_64                                       1:1.1.1k-6.el8_5                                        @Common
```